# MatLab sqrt symbol in title

Tags: matlab, latex

How to place sqrt symbol in title of plot, i tried this but didn't worked :

```
title(['\sqrt{2E/T}','cos(2\pif_', int2str(i),'t - \theta) + n(t)'],'Interpreter','latex');
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
title('$$\sqrt{f}$$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',13)
```

Comment: Also `\pif` should be `\pi f` since (La)TeX commands don't behave like escape characters.

Comment: I need to output in title not only one sqrt but and another part of string.

Comment: @govnokoder__ The answer correctly points out the solution but doesn't use your string.  If your input string to `title` is `['$\sqrt{2E/T}','cos(2\pi f_', int2str(i),'t - \theta) + n(t)$']`, it should work.  Note: `$` or `$$` will have the same effect for Matlab usage but are very different in actual LaTeX.

Comment: If it works please mark as the correct Answer. Please mark it as the valid answer. Thanks